# I need a complex template which can be used to list a group of similar content

Tags: c#, asp.net, backbone.js

I want to list a group of similar templates(which contains photos,texts and hyperlinks in a certain layout) on my web page.

[image]

So I'd like to know some technologies which can provide me the ability to develop my own template so that I can feed this template with paths of photos, text and hyperlinks and the template will arrange the layout.

I am thinking of using Customer Control + Repeater to do this job.
But I think there could be some other really brilliant technologies which can do the same thing in a easier way.

I'd love to see the name of technologies and code to demonstrate how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASP.NET, repeater is fair choice, you can easily build your any kind of template. And you can use server side tags too.

If you are willing to bind your data at client side, there are lot of client side technologies available to bind Json data, such as Jquery template, Knockout.js etc. (you can also explore other client side data binding technologies such as backbone.js, ember.js, batman.js)

[Here](http://paulhammant.com/2012/02/13/client-side-mvc-frameworks-compared/) is the list of technologies and examples.

another good read about Javascript framework:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/01/rich-javascript-applications-the-seven-frameworks-throne-of-js-2012/